# Extra space deletion in files

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I am using the below code which duplicates the entries of a file valar.csv and enters values in the columns .

```sh
awk '
NR==1   {print; next}
        {$1=$1; print}
        {$2 = $2 "D"; $3 = 3; $4 = ($4==1?2:1); $5 = $6 = " "; $7 = "Y"}
1' OFS='\t' valar.csv
```

But it also considers if there are any extra space in the file and treats that as a row and updates the values.

Can you please let know how can I modify my commands to not to consider extra space.

My output looks like this if the file has extra space in it:The last row which shows (D 3 1 Y is not expected how to trim that extra spcae issue???

```
SECURITY_ID     TRADE_ID        COUNTERPARTY_TYPE       SIDE    CUSTOMER_ACC_TYPE       COMMISSION      RELATED_PTY     NON_RESIDENT
1350Z77M0       20200922011102686632    1       1       2       30      N       N
1350Z77M0       20200922011102686632D   3       2                       Y       N
1350Z77S0       20200922011102786632    1       2       1       30      Y       N
1350Z77S0       20200922011102786632D   3       1                       Y       N

        D       3       1                       Y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
NR==1   {print; next}
/[^[:blank:]]/{print; $2 = $2 "D"; $3 = 3; $4 = ($4==1?2:1); $5 = $6 = " "; $7 = "Y"}
' OFS='\t' valar.csv
```

Comment: Small requirement change,please help.Input values separated by , and out put shd also ,separated
        {$1=$1; print}
        {$2 = $2 "D"; $3 = 3; $4 = ($4==1?2:1); $5 = $6 = " "; $7 = "Y"}
1' OFS='\t' valar.csv

SECURITY_ID,TRADE_ID,COUNTERPARTY_TYPE,SIDE,CUSTOMER_ACC_TYPE,COMMISSION,RELATED_PTY,NON_RESIDENT
1350Z77M0,20200922011102686632,1,1,2,30,N,N
Output expected:
SECURITY_ID,TRADE_ID,COUNTERPARTY_TYPE,SIDE,CUSTOMER_ACC_TYPE,COMMISSION,RELATED_PTY,NON_RESIDENT
1350Z77M0,20200922011102686632,1,1,2,30,N,N
1350Z77M0,20200922011102686632D,3,2,,,Y,N

Comment: @Flower would you mind reading the awk manual page?  You might find some interesting command  line parameters and awk variables?  FS, OFS for example.